# Nested parameters in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to nest parameterisation with pytest where the values for one parameter are dependent on the selected value of another parameter? All questions and examples I've found are looking at combining different parameters, even if they refer to this as "nesting".

I'm looking to replace a test which follows this basic structure:

```py
from pytest import mark, fixture

families = {
    'Rubble':
        {
            'members': ['Barnie', 'Bam-Bam']
        },
    'Simpson':
        {
            'members': ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart']
        }
}

@mark.parametrize('family', families.values(), ids = families, scope='class')
class TestFamily():
    
    @fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
    def expensiveIOactivities(self, family):
        """Some set of expensive IO activities that only needs running once per class."""
        # return family['members'][:-1] # Uncomment to see tests fail
        return family['members']
    
    def test_correctnumberofmembers(self, family, expensiveIOactivities):
        assert len(expensiveIOactivities) == len(family['members'])

    def test_allmembers(self, family, expensiveIOactivities):
        """Using all works but debugging is ugly"""
        assert all(member in expensiveIOactivities for member in family['members'])

    def test_allmembers_withnicerfailmessage(self, family, expensiveIOactivities):
        """All can be improved with a custom message - but this leads to extra boilerplate"""
        memberpresent = {member: member in expensiveIOactivities for member in family['members']}
        assert (
            all(memberpresent.values())
        ), f'Missing members: {", ".join(member for member, present in memberpresent.items() if not present)}'

    def test_foreachmember(self, family, expensiveIOactivities):
        """This will fail as soon as it finds the first missing member and provide no info on other missing members"""
        for member in family['members']:
            assert member in expensiveIOactivities
```

Ideally I would like to have a setup that looks like this:

```py
from pytest import mark, fixture

families = {
    'Rubble':
        {
            'members': ['Barnie', 'Bam-Bam']
        },
    'Simpson':
        {
            'members': ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart']
        }
}

@mark.parametrize('family', families.values(), ids = families, scope='class')
class TestFamily():
    
    @fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
    def expensiveIOactivities(self, family):
        """Some set of expensive IO activities that only needs running once per class."""
        # return family['members'][:-1] # Uncomment to see tests fail
        return family['members']
    
    def test_correctnumberofmembers(self, family, expensiveIOactivities):
        assert len(expensiveIOactivities) == len(family['members'])

    @mark.parametrize('member', family['members'])
    def test_memberispresent(self, member, expensiveIOactivities):
        """This is basic construct I would like, but it leads to a test collection error"""
        assert member in expensiveIOactivities
```

This should result in test collection along the lines of:

```
<Class TestFamily>
    <Function test_correctnumberofmembers[Rubble]>
    <Function test_memberispresent[Rubble-Barnie]>
    <Function test_memberispresent[Rubble-Bam-Bam]>
    <Function test_correctnumberofmembers[Simpson]>
    <Function test_memberispresent[Simpson-Homer]>
    <Function test_memberispresent[Simpson-Marge]>
    <Function test_memberispresent[Simpson-Bart]>
```

but it doesn't work as the value for `family` is not accessible in this way at collection time:

```
=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________ ERROR collecting test_families_nestedparameters.py ______________
test_families_nestedparameters.py:15: in <module>
    class TestFamily():
test_families_nestedparameters.py:26: in TestFamily
    @mark.parametrize('member', family['members'])
E   NameError: name 'family' is not defined
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR test_families_nestedparameters.py - NameError: name 'family' is not def...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
===================== 8 tests collected, 1 error in 0.28s =====================
```

I've tried using a function and a factory but this falls at the same fundamental issue - the availability of the data at collection time to be used for test case generation.

Using a customer `pytest_generate_tests` hook leads to too many runs of `test_correctnumberofmembers`:

```py
from pytest import fixture


families = {
    'Rubble':
        {
            'members': ['Barnie', 'Bam-Bam']
        },
    'Simpson':
        {
            'members': ['Homer', 'Marge', 'Bart']
        }
}


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    """Using a customer pytest_generate_tests requires every test function to include all parameters
    in the signature AND creates multiple copies of all test functions
    """
    ids = []
    parameters = ['family', 'member']
    values = []
    for familyname, familydata in families.items():
        for member in familydata['members']:
            ids.append('_'.join([familyname, member]))
            values.append([familydata, member])
    metafunc.parametrize(parameters, values, ids=ids, scope='class')

class TestFamily():
    
    @fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
    def expensiveIOactivities(self, family):
        """Some set of expensive IO activities that only needs running once per class."""
        # return family['members'][:-1] # Uncomment to see tests fail
        return family['members']
    
    def test_correctnumberofmembers(self, family, member, expensiveIOactivities):
        """This test should only be created ONCE per family. In this approach it is created once per member."""
        assert len(expensiveIOactivities) == len(family['members'])

    def test_memberispresent(self, family, member, expensiveIOactivities):
        assert member in expensiveIOactivities
```

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work? In the real version the equivalent of `families` also contains a path to a file which should be read during the `expensiveIOactivities` as well as the expected results.

The above code is available on a gist: https://gist.github.com/MusicalNinjaRandInt/a80142bc2e9d4bc4cbf232c99de4f82f